# dynamically add instances of a model in Django forms

Tags: django, forms, model

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class CalEvents(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=False, blank=True)
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True)
    activity_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Activity, type and code for the calendar events of @{}".format(self.user.username)
```

What I would like to know is how can I dynamically add instances of that model with forms. I'm imagining something like having a form for the first instance (with fields "activity", "activity_type" and "activity_code") and then, if the user clicks a "plus sign" (or whatever), (s)he can add a second, third...Nth instance to the database.

Comment: Something like dynamically adding `extra` in formset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality using Django's inline formsets.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

It will allow you to declare a form which can be used dynamically to add multiple instances of a model.

Comment: Oh, that is perfect! Thanks!